# Why am I getting this segmentation fault?

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

```
int main() {
    int fd;     //  File Descriptor for the integer file
    int pagesize=getpagesize(); //  To store the size of virtual page

    printf("\nPage size is %d bytes.\n100 integers require %lu bytes\n",pagesize,100*sizeof(int));
    void *data; //  This is the pointer which will store the returned pointer when mmap() is called

    fd=open("integer", O_RDWR); 

    data=mmap((caddr_t)0, pagesize, PROT_WRITE | PROT_READ, MAP_SHARED, fd,0);
    close(fd);

    sprintf((char*)data,"%d",100);

    return 0;
}
```

This returns a Segmentation Fault 11

Comment: You could check if mmap() failed. If it did, call `perror()` or otherwise inspect `errno` to learn why it failed. You also need to check if open() failed.

Comment: Your file "integer" probably does not exist; you will have to create it first with an appropriate length, a zero-length file will not do... If you open it with `O_CREAT`, write some (enough for your data) bytes to it before mmapping (seek()ing will do also).

Answer (score 3):

You should check for errors from `open` and `mmap`. Also, compile with warnings and include the necessary include files. `mmap` especially needs a correct prototype on many systems because of its off_t arguments which could break things when you pass it a 0 as a last argument.

But that's not enough. Does the file exist and is non-zero size?  `mmap` can happily map pages beyond the end of a file, but access to those pages will result in faults. If you actually want to the data to be written to the file you need to make sure it's long enough for it. Use `ftruncate` for that.

Also, I wonder which museum you found your documentation if it mentions `caddr_t` as the first argument to `mmap`, but that's beside the point, if that compiles it should also work.